# The disappearing scroll bar

Tags: macos

I found that many apps have disappearing scroll bar.

For example, this:

[image]

actually has scroll bar if I scroll with my track pad. (and I have no way to screenshot it as it keeps get disappearing).

I found it inconvenient for me, is there any way I can let it stay on all the time? thx

I'm using apple mouse on MBP, and the Operating System is,

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.7
BuildVersion:   19H512
```

Answer (score 9):

System Preferences > General and in block "Show scroll bars" select "Always"

[image]